# Error when Inserting date using # # format

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, insert

There appears to be an error in Access 2007. I am using Windows 2010 and my regional setting in New Zealand, which uses a dd/mm/yyyy format.

With the following query, the DateReleased value is 29/04/2016

```
INSERT INTO VERSIONNUMBER ([DateReleased],[Major],[Minor],[Release],[Build])
VALUES (#29/04/2016#,4,11,4,29)
```

With the next query, the [DateReleased] value is 5/04/2015

```
INSERT INTO VERSIONNUMBER ([DateReleased],[Major],[Minor],[Release],[Build]) 
VALUES (#4/05/2016#,4,11,5,4)
```

Access appears to default to US format if it can (i.e. if the day value < 13) otherwise writes correct NZ format.

Is this a known error and if so, is there a fix?

Comment: There's one easy answer: **Do not - never ever!! - use culture specific date literals!** Stick with ISO 8601 ODBC or universal (unseparated) format. Culture dependant date formats will - sooner or later - turn into severe pain...

Comment: If they really wanted to they could just force the date into the format they want by using Format.  Format (#04/05/2004#, "dd/mm/yyyy").  It seems a little hackish but whatever.

Comment: Sorry - the DateReleased value for the second query is 5/04/2016, not 5/04/2016.

Comment: Hi Shnugo.  Could you please give an example of inserting a date value using a universal (or unseparated) format?  I am a little surprised that Access decides to treat the date as though it is in US format if it doesn't cause an error, and ignoring the Windows regional setting but hey - that's life.  if there is a way to write a universal date, please let me have it.

Comment: Hi MikeS.  Thanks for your comment.  The Insert Query is written in Delphi 2007 and this does use a Format statement as follows:

Comment: Hi MikeS.  Thanks for your comment.  The Insert Query is written in Delphi 2007 and this does use a Format statement as follows:                             
    s := FormatDateTime('#d/mm/yyyy#', EncodeDate(year,month,day));
but then the resulting string is used in the SQL Insert query. I just didn't expect MS Access to behave like this ...

Comment: In VBA, Using CurrentDB.Execute, Date format is always mm/dd/yyyy, no mater what your Windows regional setting are.

Comment: OK so this question has been more-or-less asked before, and it is apparent that Access requires any date to be cast into the required format using the Format statement.  However, it doesn't work when writing Delphi code, as Format is a standard Delphi procedure.  Any ideas on how to correctly format the date using Delphi?

Comment: As a final comment, I have rewritten the Access INSERT query in Delphi to always write the date in US format (MM/dd/yyyy) and let the regional settings handle how the date is presented when the table is opened in Access.  What threw me is the "helpful" Access feature which enters the date in US format if it does not cause an error, otherwise in the dd/mm/yyyy format.  Quite bizarre.  Thanks for all your help.